# Transit though Heathrow from US to India with an expired H-1B stamp but a valid Canada visa stamp

Tags: uk, transit-visas

My travel is through British Airways From Chicago-->Heathrow-->India and I am travelling to India for my H-1B visa stamp renewal. I depart the same day I land in Heathrow from the same terminal and my baggage will be checked to my final destination in India.

I understand I would normally need a Direct Airside Transit Visa (DATV) to transit through Heathrow since my H-1B stamp has expired but I do hold a valid Canadian visa.

Is it still possible to travel without a transit visa under the Transit without Visa scheme (TWOV) since I hold a valid Canadian visa although I am travelling from the US.

Comment: How long ago did you last enter the US?

Comment: I wonder if this is relevant: https://www.gov.uk/government/news/transit-visa-2 -- It suggests a visa for Canada is insufficient if you are not travelling from Canada.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The language allows TWOV for those traveling to or from Canada. The wording is: "...a valid visa for entry to Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the United States of America provided the person is en-route to or from those countries..."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: That's what I thought I wrote but maybe I phrased it badly with too many negatives.